# How to execute php file inside a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to execute a php file through terminal or through the browser inside a laravel project?

When I do php filename.php I get the file as a text in response.
I also tried saving the file inside the public folder and accesing through the browser but it is the same.

I'm working with laravel 7.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation

Comment: It might be down to your server configuration, some similar issues reported at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-display-regular-php-files-from-inside-the-public-folder

Answer (score 0):

You can put it inside your public directory. If your application has a domain of localhost you can access it via localhost/script.php. BUT this is extremely ill-advised as you are opening yourself to potential vulnerabilities depending on what your script does.

If it is for testing then fine. Otherwise you will have to put that somewhere in your application say app/scripts/script.php where it cannot be accessed via the browser (the only point of stand-alone scripts in web application is for CRON tasks or for CLI commands

Or else you could...

make filename.blade.php file. put it in resources/views/filename.blade.php and execute it using routes routes/web.php

```
Route::get("/filename", function(){
    return view('filename');
});
```

Comment: No. It was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: When you put it inside public you need a webserver like apache or nginx ... is it installed in your system.,...

Comment: I'm using nginx on ubuntu

Comment: Hope your nginx server is runing or else restart it by running sudo service nginx restart ...you can copy the filename.php to the nginx web folder  or give a softlink to the larvels publicfolder to the nginx webfolder and run localhost/filename.php ...

Comment: make sure you have php7 installed in nginx https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/installing-nginx-with-php7-fpm-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts-lemp/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having the same issue I used tinker to execute my php code. Just did php artisan tinker and paste the code.